# NSString to UInt64

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uint64

How do you convert from `NSString` to `UInt64`?

For example, something like this if a `UInt64Value` helper method existed:

```
NSString *value = @"1234567";
UInt64 convertedValue = [value UInt64Value];
```

I am trying to do this in an iOS project.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To pitch another possibility for completeness:

```
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:value];
unsigned long long convertedValue = 0;
[scanner scanUnsignedLongLong:&convertedValue];
return convertedValue;
```

... check the result on `scanUnsignedLongLong` if you want to differentiate between finding a value of 0 and finding something that isn't a number.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString * num = @"123456";

NSNumberFormatter * numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
NSNumber *  number = [numberFormatter numberFromString:num];
unsigned long long valueUInt64 = number.unsignedLongLongValue;
```

Comment: Why do you use this over [stringValue longLongValue]; ?

Comment: because you are asking for unsigned long long :)

Comment: I am not familiar with this datatype, long long...perhaps an explanation of it would help? It sounds really strange because I've never encountered such a thing. The 64 bit value space allows at maximum a UInt64, so what is a long long?

Comment: Also another question, what happens if you run this on a 32 bit device? Does it still work?

Comment: I guess @Alexandru you have to search it on your own.I have just nsnumberformatter and found it would be a help for you :). you can have look at this http://superuser.com/questions/698312/if-32-bit-machines-can-only-handle-numbers-up-to-232-why-can-i-write-100000000

Comment: I guess it depends upon the number.if the number is huge and cannot be accommodated in 32 bit.Then it will be stored on 2 32-bit portions. Then it will work.You can have further search also :)

Comment: In C, a `long` is 32 bits (on most platforms).  To ensure that one is getting a 64 bit value, the `long long` type exists.  To get the unsigned version, one simply prefaces the type with `unsigned`, as is done for any integer type.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is incorrect, try it with `@"18446744073709551615"` (that is the maximum `unsigned long long` value). It is not immediately clear whether this is a bug or feature of `NSNumberFormatter`. The answer by @Tommy works correctly in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Yeah, makes a bit more sense now. I realize coming from the Windows world things are a bit different in the Linux landscape. P.S. you can set `valueUInt64` as a `UInt64` directly: `UInt64 valueUInt64 = number.unsignedLongLongValue;` I guess it makes sense why they call it a `long long` now, as it may have to be stored into two 32-bit `long`'s to ensure it is actually 64 bits long, in a 32-bit architecture.

Comment: @CRD good spot.I verified it and it gives zero value when tested with max value of unsigned long long.

Comment: Then we gotta give this one to Tommy.

Comment: Yep confirmed this does not work for @"18446744073709551615". @Tommy's answer works correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtoull(const char *, char **, int)` as following:

```
NSString *value = @"1234567";
UInt64 convertedValue = strtoull([value UTF8String], NULL, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get a `UInt64` with `longLongValue`

```
NSString *str = @"23147653105732";
UInt64 uint64 = [str longLongValue];
```

Another way to get an `int64` is:

```
NSString *str = @"23147653105732";
int64_t int64_t = atoll([str UTF8String]);
```